# How to show contents of axes object when using pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to wrap my head around using axes-objects in conjunction with a Pandas-dataframe (object df in the following snippet):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig=plt.figure()
axes=fig.add_subplot(111)

for key, grp in df.groupby(['bondYear', 'bondQuarter']):
    axes = grp['priceAvg'].plot(label=key, ax=axes)
```

This runs through without any complaints, but now I'm looking for a way to actually make my plot show (and later save to *.png like with using savefig()). plt.show() works but opens two windows, one showing my plot and the other one being empty, so that's not it.

Apparently I'm missing something regarding the use of matplotlib, can you help me out?

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't reassign your plot to `axes`, although that should not matter. Try this.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
for key, grp in df.groupby(['bondYear', 'bondQuarter']):
    grp['priceAvg'].plot(label=key, ax=ax)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
plt.savefig('figname.png')
```

You can also plot them all at once without using iteration doing the following but you are easily able to control the legend.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).plot(ax=ax)
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, that made thing clearer to me. Upon trying it out I realized the actual problem was an earlier section containting a df.plot(); plt.savefig(); plt.clf() ...